# How to best deal with C++ classes that need to have an object of self type?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm a beginner in C++ with some experience in other programming languages (i.e. Python, Javascript).
I have a couple of questions concerning "recursive" classes - classes that are declared within themselves - in C++.

### Question 1

For a class with constructor, I understand that declaring it within itself, would cause its declaration to be incomplete and thus the compiler would have no way of working out the size of its objects.
I learned thus far that a class declaration can only contain a **pointer to self type** or **a static object of self type**.
However, I don't understand what the **benefits** are to either approach? My goal is to use a class much like a tree structure/network, where each node stores its parent node and child nodes!

### Question 2

Both parent and child nodes would be set with class functions. How do I declare self types within a function of the same class? Do I also use static or pointers? How do I initialise correctly in this case?

#### example.cpp

```cpp
#include "Point.hpp"

class Node {
    //Node parent; // ERROR

    // Option 1: Pointer
    Node * parent;

    // Option 2: Static
    static Node parent;

    vector<Node> children;

public:
    Node(float _x, float _y, float _z);
    void setChildren(/* some params */);

    float x, y, z;
};
```

#### example.hpp

```cpp
Node::Node(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
}

void Node::setChildren(/* some params */) {
    Node child1, child2; // ERROR: how to declare here?

    // do stuff with the parameters...

    child1 = {/*x1, y1, z1*/}; // ERROR: how to initialise?
    child2 = {/*x2, y2, z2*/}; // ERROR: how to initialise?
    children.push_back(child1);
    children.push_back(child2)
```

I hope somebody can explain this to me! I'm really lost here.

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only reason `Node child1;` would give an error is because you are trying to default construct an object that doesn't have a default constructor

Comment: `static` won't work here. It will cause a single object not associated with any specific object of that class to be created. This means you'll have only one parent object, whether you have 0, 1 or more other objects created.

Comment: @UnholySheep - Thanks, I must have confused how you're supposed to declare variables (e.g. `int num;`) vs. classes with constructors!

Comment: @LouisCloete - OK, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: `class Node { Node parent; };` would be infinitely big, because each `parent` would also contain a `parent`

Comment: @Caleth - As I understand it, upon declaration of the first Node object, a new parent Node object would be declared, with an incomplete declaration of the very first node, which would mean that the compiler would not be able to figure out the size of the objects?

Comment: A data member occupies space *within* the object. The compiler *could* work out the size, it would be infinite.

Comment: It couldn't even be infinite, because the inner one and the outer one would have to be the same size. Imagine a taped shut cardboard box, and inside the cardboard box is a vase of flowers, and another taped shut cardboard box the same size as the first box. It doesn't make sense. The box can't contain stuff that's the same size as itself.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Thanks, great analogy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your declaration and definition in the wrong files. The class declaration should be in the header file (.hpp) and the function/constructor etc definitions should be in the source file (.cpp). You will need to including the header file in the source file like this:

### example.hpp

```
#include "Point.hpp"

class Node {
    // Use Option 1: Pointer
    Node* parent = nullptr;

    list<Node> children;

public:
    Node(float _x, float _y, float _z);
    void setChildren(/* some params */);

    float x, y, z;
};
```

### example.cpp

```
#include "example.hpp"

Node::Node(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
}

void Node::setChildren(/* some params */) {
    Node child1 = {x1, y1, z1};
    Node child2 = {x2, y2, z2};

    // do stuff with the parameters...

    push_back(child1);
    push_back(child2);
}
```

One way to set the parent pointer is to add a new `push_back` function to the `Node` class to set the pointer on the new child object before/or after adding it into the `children` list.

Also you initialize child1/2 like this in C++.

```
Node child1 = {x1, y1, z1};
Node child2 = {x2, y2, z2};
```

### "However, I don't understand what the benefits are to either approach?"

In C++ you have the `this` pointer at all times in your member functions meaning there is no need for a `self` pointer like you do in other programming languages `this` is your `self` pointer.

Also If you are planning what I see that you are planning, in order for this to work you won't want to use `vector` for the `children`, as a `vector` uses contiguous memory, this will invalidate all pointers/iterators to it once the internal memory to the `vector` gets resized (could happen on `push_back` and other operations i.e. erase/insert). Meaning the easier thing to do would be to use a `list` instead of a `vector` in this case. This way the parent back pointers won't get invalidated when a new child gets added/removed (with `push_back` for example).

See the documentation for std::vector and std::list.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Oh, my bad! I must have switched the titles above. Sorry! 

Do I set the parent pointer on the new child object like this: `child1.parent = this`?

Noted, about the initialisation of the children. Thanks!

OK, I'll look into vectors vs lists straightaway.

One other question I have is, why does this work with `Node * parent;`? I mean, how does declaring the Node inside the Node class with a pointer work? What's happening here?

Thank you for your elaborate reply!!

Comment: Yes you set the parent pointers in the child class like that, Also you parent pointer should be defaulted to the `nullptr` (answer edited).
Pointers and references do not need a full object to be initialised and therefore can be declared within a `class`/`struct` that is not yet a complete type. This also counts for the `vector<Node>` and `list<Node>` as these objects only contain pointer(s) to `Node` they also don't need a complete type. However it would be an error if they did.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything works like a charm and I've learned a lot!! :)